# Paperclip 4.0 does not save image and name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a product model

```
#(product.rb):
def get_image_from_link 
unless url.blank?
encoded_url  = URI.encode(url)
self.image  = URI.parse(url)
end
```

With the following validations:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage/
validates_attachment_file_name :image, matches: [/png\Z/, /jpe?g\Z/]
```

I am parsing some thousands of URLs to Paperclip 4.0. Paperclip is not saving the image and the name in the database for some of the URLs.

Problem is, I cannot see any error and I cannot see the answer from the problematic urls. Instead of writing the SQL back it states ROLLBACK. Any idea?

This URL would work:
http://i.stylepit.com/common/225162/33/225162_1_2_33.jpg
This URL would not work:
http://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/Levi/clothing/658190078-front-grid.jpg

Here the rails log:

```
Product Load (12.5ms)  SELECT `products`.* FROM `products`  WHERE (`products`.`id` BETWEEN 6543 AND 16640)
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/vw/7dfpgzk12bq2rvyt0xf43n_w0000gn/T/54c9b33af60ed43f767d65879eef4ae520160125-89544-1ng82hf.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/vw/7dfpgzk12bq2rvyt0xf43n_w0000gn/T/54c9b33af60ed43f767d65879eef4ae520160125-89544-1ng82hf.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/vw/7dfpgzk12bq2rvyt0xf43n_w0000gn/T/54c9b33af60ed43f767d65879eef4ae520160125-89544-1ng82hf.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "500x600!" '/var/folders/vw/7dfpgzk12bq2rvyt0xf43n_w0000gn/T/3cabc5720daa884aae0baca2b9deff8620160125-89544-d33v1w'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/vw/7dfpgzk12bq2rvyt0xf43n_w0000gn/T/54c9b33af60ed43f767d65879eef4ae520160125-89544-1ng82hf.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/vw/7dfpgzk12bq2rvyt0xf43n_w0000gn/T/54c9b33af60ed43f767d65879eef4ae520160125-89544-1ng82hf.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/vw/7dfpgzk12bq2rvyt0xf43n_w0000gn/T/54c9b33af60ed43f767d65879eef4ae520160125-89544-1ng82hf.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "300x400!" '/var/folders/vw/7dfpgzk12bq2rvyt0xf43n_w0000gn/T/3cabc5720daa884aae0baca2b9deff8620160125-89544-opiint'
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Product Exists (7.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `products`  WHERE (`products`.`slug` = BINARY '606557062827' AND `products`.`id` != 6543) LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/vw/7dfpgzk12bq2rvyt0xf43n_w0000gn/T/abd8cc1fc2c7b161afbe4bd1cf9793b720160125-89544-1xboc34.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/vw/7dfpgzk12bq2rvyt0xf43n_w0000gn/T/abd8cc1fc2c7b161afbe4bd1cf9793b720160125-89544-1xboc34.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/vw/7dfpgzk12bq2rvyt0xf43n_w0000gn/T/abd8cc1fc2c7b161afbe4bd1cf9793b720160125-89544-1xboc34.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "500x600!" '/var/folders/vw/7dfpgzk12bq2rvyt0xf43n_w0000gn/T/2185eefda52e42bea24b1207c03ca9a420160125-89544-1i2c9ku'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/vw/7dfpgzk12bq2rvyt0xf43n_w0000gn/T/abd8cc1fc2c7b161afbe4bd1cf9793b720160125-89544-1xboc34.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/vw/7dfpgzk12bq2rvyt0xf43n_w0000gn/T/abd8cc1fc2c7b161afbe4bd1cf9793b720160125-89544-1xboc34.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/vw/7dfpgzk12bq2rvyt0xf43n_w0000gn/T/abd8cc1fc2c7b161afbe4bd1cf9793b720160125-89544-1xboc34.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "300x400!" '/var/folders/vw/7dfpgzk12bq2rvyt0xf43n_w0000gn/T/2185eefda52e42bea24b1207c03ca9a420160125-89544-1w7jcw8'
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Product Exists (5.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `products`  WHERE (`products`.`slug` = BINARY '738372485742' AND `products`.`id` != 6550) LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
^C[2016-01-25 13:52:16] INFO  going to shutdown ...
^CCommand :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/vw/7dfpgzk12bq2rvyt0xf43n_w0000gn/T/d333c5315c2c15bc42bdd50421924c1420160125-89544-mvcfe7.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/vw/7dfpgzk12bq2rvyt0xf43n_w0000gn/T/d333c5315c2c15bc42bdd50421924c1420160125-89544-mvcfe7.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/vw/7dfpgzk12bq2rvyt0xf43n_w0000gn/T/d333c5315c2c15bc42bdd50421924c1420160125-89544-mvcfe7.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "500x600!" '/var/folders/vw/7dfpgzk12bq2rvyt0xf43n_w0000gn/T/10f8983119040bef062a26410feb02a420160125-89544-fk9653'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/vw/7dfpgzk12bq2rvyt0xf43n_w0000gn/T/d333c5315c2c15bc42bdd50421924c1420160125-89544-mvcfe7.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/vw/7dfpgzk12bq2rvyt0xf43n_w0000gn/T/d333c5315c2c15bc42bdd50421924c1420160125-89544-mvcfe7.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/vw/7dfpgzk12bq2rvyt0xf43n_w0000gn/T/d333c5315c2c15bc42bdd50421924c1420160125-89544-mvcfe7.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "300x400!" '/var/folders/vw/7dfpgzk12bq2rvyt0xf43n_w0000gn/T/10f8983119040bef062a26410feb02a420160125-89544-l1ol9t'
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Product Exists (3.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `products`  WHERE (`products`.`slug` = BINARY '609421259727' AND `products`.`id` != 6557) LIMIT 1
   (2.1ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Controller actions:

```
before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Schema:

```
create_table "products", force: true do |t| t.string "title" t.text "description", limit: 2147483647 t.string "shop_id", limit: 128 t.string "color_id" t.string "size_id" t.string "brand_id" t.text "url", limit: 2147483647 t.datetime "created_at" t.datetime "updated_at" t.string "image_file_name" t.string "image_content_type" t.integer "image_file_size" t.datetime "image_updated_at"
```

Product Params:

def params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :size_id, :category3, :oldprice, :newprice, :color_id, :brand_id, :image, :image2, :image3, :category_id [])

Comment: Are you permitting your params correctly?

Comment: Could you show your schema and controller actions for the file upload please

Comment: you could just update your question with these please, very difficult to read as a comment

Comment: try content_type: { :content_type => ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png'] as your validation for now

Comment: with that validation nothing gets processed even the old links do not work any longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was params. Not all fields in the database were filled. Therefore no file downloaded and saved by paperclip.

Thanks for your help!